# MySQL row count > 1 but SELECT only returns 1?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a simple MySQL query with PDO, which is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE variable=:variable`, and then I execute it.  I grab the affected row count with the `rowCount();` function, and that returns 20, for the specific criteria I am after.  However, when I move onto the `while statement`, only one result is being echoed.  Also, this is a new problem, literally just started happening 20 minutes ago.  Suggestions?

**Edit to Add Code**

```
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM files WHERE `subject`=:subject ORDER BY title");
        $stmt->execute(array(':subject' => $_GET['subject']));
        $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();     
        if ($row_count > 0) {
            echo $row_count;
            echo "<div class='row'>";
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=:userID");
                $stmt->execute(array(':userID' => $row['userID']));
                $resultsArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $resultsArray = $resultsArray[0];
                $fullName = $resultsArray['name'];
                $authorEmail = $resultsArray['email'];
             }
        }
```

Comment: I suggest to post your code so people can try to spot errors on it..

Comment: Please share code, the while statement, etc...

Comment: @Nelson sure, but the same code was working before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to your `$stmt` variable inside the while loop which is based on that same `$stmt` variable.

Replace your following code:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=:userID");
            $stmt->execute(array(':userID' => $row['userID']));
            $resultsArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

for this one:

```
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=:userID");
            $stmt2->execute(array(':userID' => $row['userID']));
            $resultsArray = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: THAT's REALLY WEIRD then.  I have had that EXACT same code for the past week no problem, yet that suddenly seemed to fix it.  Any idea why it suddenly didn't work however?

Comment: Your while loop was possibly be iterating by a number equal to the users with `userID=:userID`, that could maybe by coincidence be the same number of your original rowCount (`20`)..

Comment: @user2252323 Was someone else working on the code?  Because this never could have worked...

Comment: @1789040 That must have been it - I've been away for the week, and someone else in the office must've just copied and pasted, but forgot to change the vars.  Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `$stmt` inside the loop, so it stops fetching rows properly.

You can change them to something like `$stmt2` (or perhaps even something more descriptive):

```
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=:userID");
            $stmt2->execute(array(':userID' => $row['userID']));
            $resultsArray = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $resultsArray = $resultsArray[0];
            $fullName = $resultsArray['name'];
            $authorEmail = $resultsArray['email'];
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the **while** block, you're executing this statement:

> $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=:userID");

which is overwriting the **$stmt** variable used in the **while** statement.